# Showing last cookie value on Relogin (i.e. Again login after logout) in Asp.net MVC with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, cookies

I am working on Asp.net MVC with Razor view engine with C#. I have a login form and on login I create a Cookie for userid, and on logout I remove this cookie evrything works fine yet. but the problem starts when I Login again it still shows the value of Previous Login's userid.

The code of creating cookie is

```
HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieId, cookieValue);
newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);
```

And to remove cookie

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieId] != null)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[cookieId].Value = null;
}
```

I have remove the cookie on login if there exist but still it is not working , please help me......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove your cookie like below,

```
if ( Request.Cookies["MyCookie"] != null )
{
    var c = new HttpCookie( "MyCookie" );
    c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays( -1 );
    Response.Cookies.Add( c );
}
```